# OEM repos (sources.list) for Dell XPS 13 9380 with Bionic

Tags: apt, dell, xps, oem

Because of a tragic accident the sources.list on my XPS 13 9380 with Bionic 18.04.03 has been rm -r ...if you know what I mean.

Everything's in place and working but I don't remember (and can not find it anywhere) the name of the OEM repository that was in 'Software & Updates' in the 'Other Software' tab/list. It was there, I saw it a couple of times but didn't care to write it down...

Can anybody with a similar configuration do me a favor, look it up and post the name of it here? Thanks in advance.

```
                                 -- || --
```

Posting here the result of my investigation, the sources.list for XPS 13 9380 with i7 (code-name 'italia-whl'):

```
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ bionic-dell-italia-whl public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ bionic-dell-italia-whl public
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ bionic-dell public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ bionic-dell public
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ bionic-dell-service public
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ bionic-dell-service public
deb http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates/ bionic-oem public
# deb-src http://oem.archive.canonical.com/updates/ bionic-oem public
```

Bye!

Comment: I meant the meaningless combinations of words like f.i. 'berlinetta-p-mlk-cfl'. They mean a particular model of computer and its configuration.

Comment: I will figure it out myself.

Comment: Looking at https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?p=513831&sid=fb486c9743e6ea65ad9f8083378146b3#p513831 it appears as it might be the `italia-whl`

Comment: Oh, yeah! There it is! Thank you, man.

Comment: Oh, NO! Close, but no banana. It's i5 processor, I have i7. :( Maybe it will work maybe not. I will try. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes. There was a "Meta package for italia-whl 08af" visible in Synaptic. Looks like 9380 is 'italia-whl'. Maybe this will help somebody some day. :)